# Filter NSArray of Arrays by One Element of Array Using NSPredicate in IOS

Tags: ios, nsarray, nspredicate, associative-array

It is possible to filter an array of strings as follows:

```
NSArray *array =  @[@"honda",@"toyota",@"ford"];
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",@"ford"];
NSArray *filtered = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

I want to search an array that contains arrays of two strings by the values for the first of the strings.  So for:

```
NSArray *cars = @[@[@"honda",@"accord"],@[@"toyota",@"corolla"],@[@"ford",@"explorer"]];
```

I want to search the first dimension (honda, toyota, ford) for @"ford"

Is there a way to tell the predicate I want to search on only the first attribute and return matching elements of the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here is the pred you need.

```
     NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF[FIRST] contains[cd] %@", @"ford"];
```